# Super Resolution implementation using Keras

Tags: keras

In keras, if I want my display the output for a given input low resolution image, what code would I use?

I tried

```
predictions = model.predict_classes(c)
```

as well as

```
get_3rd_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input], [model.layers[2].output])
layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output([c])[0]
```

However, both of these do not work.

Comment: What is the error you get? Is `c` a valid input for the model?

Comment: Could you explain "do not work" and "super resolution"?

Comment: You have to explain your super resolution algorithm briefly in order for others to help. Typically, for super resolution, you will need an output as an image patch in the up scaled resolution. So, prediction obviously won't work for your purpose here. The latter may work but you have to configure it in the right way.